# Android Fragment in alert dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making a search page for an android application.  I want to add some search filters in some sort of modal and the suggestions on the internet say I should use an AlertDialog with a fragment to show my custom filters.  I have managed to get the fragment to show in the dialog but the code associated with the fragment such as onCreate is not being called.  When I use the fragment directly in an activity its onCreate gets called but not when it is being loaded by the AlertDialog.  Is there something I am doing wrong or should I be doing this another way?

This is the code used to open the dialog

```
SearchFilterDialogFragment dialog = new SearchFilterDialogFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
            if (prev != null) {
                fragmentTransaction.remove(prev);
            }
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            dialog.show(fragmentTransaction,"dialog");
```

This is the code for the dialog configuration

```
public class SearchFilterDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank,null)).setTitle("Search Filters")
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.filter_dialogue_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.filter_dialogue_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });

    return builder.create();



}
```

This is the test fragment that will eventually have actual filters in it

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {



public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DialogFragment *is* the Fragment. It manages the Fragment lifecycle. Everything you want inside BlankFragment should be inside SearchFilterDialogFragment. You don't need BlankFragment.

To answer your question as to why BlankFragment's code is not geting called,
it's because there's nothing referencing or instantiating BlankFragment at all. 
The code:

```
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank,null))
```

Inflates the fragment_blank layout into the DialogFragment, but it does *not* start BlankFragment code.

**Proper usage of DialogFragment with custom setView**:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Set all the title, button etc. for the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Search Filters");

    //Get LayoutInflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    //Inflate the layout but ALSO store the returned view to allow us to call findViewById
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank,null);

    //Do all the initial code regarding the view, as you would in onCreate normally
    view.findViewById(R.id.some_view);

    //Finally, give the custom view to the AlertDialog builder
    builder.setView(view);
}
```

Comment: I never mentioned it before but on tablet devices I want to use the fragment in the same view as the search results.  Do I just methodise the the inner workings and re-implement them in the fragment I will use on the page? I was hoping to use the one fragment in both locations.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#DialogOrEmbed You'll need a container view added to your layout, and programatically detect if it's a tablet. Then embed if tablet, or show as dialog if not.

Comment: So a diallog fragment is just a fragment that can be displayed as a dialog if you want?

Comment: Yes, that's a way to think about it.